# Blazor - update HTML on button click following async get request

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, .net-5, webassembly

Been at this for two days now. There are many similar questions, but none of the answers have successfully worked for me. I come from using C# for the controller side and plain JavaScript for everything client side in ASP.NET Core. I am familiar with the .NET environment but really struggling with Blazor.

Problem: To get started with Blazor, the first thing I'm trying to do is set up a very simple view (razor page since this is Blazor). On a button click, I am calling an HttpGet from a controller - I can verify in browser debugging (network tab) that the call DID go through, and a Notes object was returned with the values I gave it in the controller. I have this code as my razor page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert Random Value" @bind="@theResponse.note1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" @onclick="TestPost">Test POST</button>
    </div>
</div>



@code {

    Notes theResponse = new Notes();

    private async Task TestPost()
    {
        theResponse = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Notes>("Test/Action4");
    }


}
```

Notes object:

```
    public class Notes
    {
        public string note1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
namespace BlazorTry1.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("[action]")]
        [ActionName("Action4")]
        public async Task<JsonResult> myStringResult1()
        {
            Notes myNotes = new Notes();
            myNotes.note1 = "YouHitTheGetRequest";
            var yourdata = myNotes;
            return Json(new { data = yourdata });
        }
    }
}
```

However, in debugging within Visual Studio - 'theResponse' remains null through step debugging.

Other answers I've read on stackoverflow confirm that in current Blazor, StateHasChanged is automatically called at the end of a Task method. I tried manually adding that, of course no change.

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious here - but I've tried quite a variation of ideas on the razor page and I am not succeeding. I read @bind

> The @bind attribute accomplishes two separate (but related) tasks:
>
> 1. Binds an expression to the value of the <Input... component
> 2. Binds a delegate that will trigger the component's ValueChanged property

I'm interpreting this wrong I'm sure but I imagined that when the Notes object had a property changed, that would fire the ValueChanged event.

Edit: Edited to correct grammar.

Comment: do you have a github repo for this ?

Comment: @yasseros https://github.com/Yafrovon/BlazorTry1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in your controller replace this

```
  public async Task<JsonResult> myStringResult1()
        {
            Notes myNotes = new Notes();
            myNotes.note1 = "YouHitTheGetRequest";
            var yourdata = myNotes;
            return Json(new { data = yourdata });
        }
```

with this

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<Notes>> myStringResult1()
        {
            Notes myNotes = new Notes();
            myNotes.note1 = "YouHitTheGetRequest";
            return myNotes; 
        }
```

Comment: This worked. Can you explain to me why the latter works and not the original? In MVC with JavaScript I've always used Task<JsonResult> and it works. What's the difference here?

And also thank you very much for taking the time to help me solve this. I really appreciate that.